# Broken links after kernel upgrade

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel, symbolic-link

After running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And upgrading my kernel as well as some other stuff and then running this twice with a reboot after each running:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I got this error the second time I ran it:

```
nk /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img.old
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
```

What does this mean and do I need to do anything about it?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Kernel Version Information:**

```
3.19.0-20-generic
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

If there is no warning shown, there is no problem.

If you reboot now, grub might not find the kernel.

Comment: The output of that command was `Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-20-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
`, so does the warning thing count as an error? Could you also please include in your answer why this sort of thing can occur and what to do if `grub` cannot find the kernel.

Comment: Hello, there are many possible errors (e.g. no space left). There is no need to worry about the Warnung, everything should be ok now.

Comment: What is a "Warnung"? Is that like nuns at war or something?

Comment: Read on here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1258597
A warning means: "something is wrong, but it doesn't make any problem"

Comment: "Warnung" was auto correct, I wanted to write "warning".

Comment: @davidbaumann Coder und Autoliebhaber? Suchst nen Job? :)